# Switching between dynamic Pickers crashes app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to React Native and need to dynamically populate a Picker depending on the value of a selected Radio Button. For example, in the following code if you select "Animals" the Picker would contain "Dog", "Cat", and "Fish" and if you selected "People" the Picker would contain "Will Smith".

However, if I select "Cat" or "Fish" from Animals and then click on the People radio button, the app crashes. When debugging I saw I was getting an Array Index Out of Bounds Exception, and I'm guessing it's probably because I'm selecting index 1 or 2 in the Animals array, but there is only 1 item in the People array. It must be trying to get index 1 or 2 from the People array, but that is obviously out of bounds.

The behavior I need is for the Picker to go back to the default option "Select one" whenever I change to a different radio button.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Picker } from 'react-native';
import RadioGroup from 'react-native-radio-buttons-group';

// Constants for currently selected radio button
const ANIMALS = 0
const PEOPLE = 1

// Constant for when nothing is selected in the Picker
const NOTHING = 'nothing'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      selectedVal: NOTHING, // Currently selected item
      radioType: ANIMALS, // Currently selected radio button
      radioValues: [
        {
          type: ANIMALS,
          label: "Animals",
        },
        {
          type: PEOPLE,
          label: "People",
        },
      ]
    }
  }
  getCategories = (type) => {
    if (type === ANIMALS) {
      return [
        "Dog", "Cat", "Fish"
      ]
    } else if (type === PEOPLE) {
      return [
        "Will Smith"
      ]
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <RadioGroup
          flexDirection="row"
          radioButtons={this.state.radioValues}
          onPress={(data) => {
            this.setState({
              radioValues: data
            })
            let selected = this.state.radioValues.find(e => e.selected === true)
            if (selected.type === ANIMALS) {
              this.setState({ radioType: ANIMALS })
            } else if (selected.type === PEOPLE) {
              this.setState({ radioType: PEOPLE })
            }
          }} />
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.selectedVal}
          style={{ height: 50, width: 250 }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue) =>
            this.setState({ selectedVal: itemValue })
          }>
          <Picker.Item label="<Select one>" value={NOTHING} />
          {
            this.getCategories(this.state.radioType).map((categoryName, index) => {
              return <Picker.Item label={categoryName} value={categoryName} key={index} />
            })
          }
        </Picker>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

This is what the app looks like:
[image]

I tried manually setting `this.state.selectedVal` back to `NOTHING` inside of `componentDidUpdate()` but the app still crashes if I select "Cat" or "Fish" from the Animals view and then switch to People. Strangely it works when I run it from a new Expo project, but not with this project where I used the react-native CLI.

Does anyone know how to fix the array index out of bounds exception?

Comment: `this.setState({
              selectedVal: NOTHING,
              radioValues: data
            })` Could you try this?

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work....after some debugging with React Devtools it looks like the `selectedIndex` inside of the Picker component is still set to 3 even after I call `this.setState({selectedValue: NOTHING})`. Is this a bug with the Picker?